# Edit / Delete based off $_GET variable?

Tags: php, get

I'm currently working on a system where if a user is logged in and they view a page that was created by them they can edit or delete it. The content of the page is determined by a `$_GET` variable. I plan on taking this variable and checking if the user owns it on the backend before doing anything to the actual data of that page.

My concerns are what if someone changes the `$_GET` variable in the URL? How does php work with `$_GET` variables? Are they defined when the page is run or could a user change that variable once on the page and modify the content of another page?

Any help on this would be great. Currently how I have it setup it should not be too big of a job to do but I just want to make sure that I"m not going to run into major security issues. Thanks.

Comment: Any user can change *any* value sent to the server, GET or otherwise.  Always validate and authorize the operation server-side before performing it.

Comment: So just like how I'm thinking of doing it. Validate that that actual page was uploaded by the user, otherwise redirect without doing anything.

Comment: You need to verify the inputs, malicious users can edit/delete your posts if there is no security.

Answer (score 0):

Just check if the GET array is set and equal to something in particular, or already in an array.

I.e.:

```
if(isset($_GET['var']) && $_GET['var'] == 'xyz')
```

In array example:

```
<?php 
$array= array ('abc','def','ghi');
if (isset($_GET['var'])){
    if (in_array($_GET['var'], $array)) {
        echo "Do something";
    }
    else {
        echo "Do something else";
    }
}
?>

<a href="file.php?var=abc">Click</a> Allowed
```

If someone tries to modify it `file.php?var=abcd` it will go to the "Do something else" since it is not part of the array.

References:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php